# Mail appears in every desktop

Tags: email

How do I remove mail from appearing in every Desktop?  I have tried to find solutions in System Preferences, but have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 4):

Right click it in the Dock > Options.
Select something other than All Desktops.

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  It worked.  Thanks very much.